# How to know what type of diagram contributes to a two-to-two process?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, conservation-laws, feynman-diagrams, interactions

There are 3 types of diagrams that can contribute to a two-to-two process; the $s$-channel, $u$-channel and $t$-channel.
How do I know what diagrams can contribute to a process?

I know that in QED, only 
$\gamma \rightarrow f\bar{f}$
vertices are allowed, where $\gamma$ is a photon, $f$ is a fermion and $\bar{f}$ is the anti-fermion.

So for the process $e^+e^- \rightarrow \mu^+ \mu^-$, only the $s$-channel is allowed and not the $t$- or $u$-channels.

Comment: Read Peskin chapters 3,4,5

Comment: All diagrams contribute to a process, upto an imposed cutoff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagrams contributing to a process are **all** connected, amputated diagrams with the desired external particles that are *consistent with the Feynman rules*.

In a tree-level 2-2 process in a theory with only trivalent vertices, as you correctly noted, the only possible diagrams are the s, t and u - channel >-< - shaped diagrams. That is, diagrams containing 2 vertices connected by a photon.

For the process $e^{+}e^{-} \to \mu^{+}\mu^{-}$ the Feynman rules eliminate all but the s-channel diagram, because the rest contain a $\gamma \mu^{\pm} e^{\mp}$ vertex, and that doesn't exist in the theory.

If instead we considered $e^{+}e^{-} \to e^{+}e^{-}$ then only the u-channel would be eliminated since it requires a vertex $\gamma e^{\pm} e^{\pm}$.